# reactjs clear date input after clicking clear button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What should I do to clear date input?, I have button that if the user clicked, it will clear the date.

```
  const [startdate, setStartDate] = useState();
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();


  const onChangedate = (e) => {
      let startDate = convertDate(e.startDate);
      let endDate = convertDate(e.endDate);
      setStartDate(startDate);
      setEndDate(endDate);
  }; 
  const handleClearfilter = () =>{
    setStartDate("");
    setEndDate("");
  }

  <DateRangePickerComponent   placeholder='Select a range' change={onChangedate} 
              style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 16}}
              />


 <Button 
    onClick={handleClearfilter}
  >
  Clear All
  </Button>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the issue that `DateRangePickerComponent` is uncontrolled and holding on to the inputted values?

Comment: any runnable code like codesandbox or Jsfiddle or codepen??

Comment: If it is a third-party component please check their documentation. If you have created it yourself please handle it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a React key to "reset" the uncontrolled input. When the React key changes React will throw away the old version and mount a new "instance".

See [fully uncontrolled component with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) for example and deeper explanation.

```
const [key, setKey] = useState(false);

...

const handleClearfilter = () =>{
  setStartDate("");
  setEndDate("");
  setKey(k => !k); // toggle React key value
}

<DateRangePickerComponent
  key={key} // <-- attach React key
  placeholder='Select a range'
  change={onChangedate} 
  style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 16}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the component, you have to feed in the values yourself.
The docs show that you require two date values since it is a data **range** input.

```
  const [startdate, setStartDate] = useState();
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();


  const onChangedate = (e) => {
      let startDate = convertDate(e.startDate);
      let endDate = convertDate(e.endDate);
      setStartDate(startDate);
      setEndDate(endDate);
  }; 
  const handleClearfilter = () =>{
    setStartDate("");
    setEndDate("");
  }

  <DateRangePickerComponent   placeholder='Select a range' change={onChangedate}   startDate={startDate} endDate={endDate}
              style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 16}}
              />


 <Button 
    onClick={handleClearfilter}
  >
  Clear All
  </Button>
```